npm install failing for multiple reasons
when running npm i --force i get this errors
or the process will take more than 1 hour
i have used UK, Germany and other countries vpn
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'D:/node_modules\check-more-types\dist\check-more-types.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
npm ERR!     at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:443:19)
npm ERR!     at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:714:18)
npm ERR!     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1129:27)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
npm ERR!     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\node_modules\cypress\lib\util.js:9:12)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32) {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\node_modules\\check-more-types\\package.json',
npm ERR!   requestPath: 'check-more-types'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v20.12.2

or it won't install these packages bluebird ,  cypress , check-more-types

Could it be related to how the path is specified? It seems like D:/node_modules\check-more-types\dist\check-more-types.js uses a forward slash in D:/ and backward slashes for the rest of the path.

@Codrin
no i have chenged that manually to hide the base path iam using before posting it

Understood, would it be possible to post the contents of your package.json, npm and node versions?
